# How to terminate all background threads?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I write a card game in C# using WPF. I use background threads doing it like:
`await (Task.Run(() => dealCards()));`
in ***async*** method to make delay in dealing cards.

In ***dealCards()*** method i use such structure as
`Action act = () => { ... };
canvasMainArea.Dispatcher.Invoke(act);`

When i restart game and redeal cards before current dealing still not finished new threads begin working with old threads, which wasnt terminated explicitly, so dealing looks chaotic.

My question is how to terminate all that threads excluding primary thread?

Comment: [Cancellation in Managed Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: As I understood this approach works only when we want to terminate our threads once, but I need to do it many times. In other way button Redeal doesnt make any sense (at least if we want to use it more than 1 time).

Comment: Every time you restart the operation, you need to create new `CancellationTokenSource`. That way you can repeat the cancellation infinite  number of times.

Comment: I have to cancel corresponding method in the beginning of "redeal" method. But every `CancellationTokenSource` is creating in this method as well. So this instance of `CancellationTokenSource` still doesnt exist in such context.

Comment: Have only one instance of `CancellationTokenSource`, store it in a field, share the instance of  `CancellationTokenSource` you have created in all methods you'd like to cancel. Then cancel it when you need.

Comment: Im sorry, may be I dont completely understand something, but in your link its written that property `IsCancellationRequested` can get value **true** only once, so there is no way to repeat cancellation for other methods. But I need to cancel it every time I click Redeal

Comment: @Altav1sta: You should only use `Task.Run` if you have CPU-bound work that would interfere with the UI's capability to update. While dealing cards is CPU-bound, it cannot possibly be a long enough operation that it's interfering with the UI thread. I recommend you simply remove all multithreading from your program.

Comment: @StephenCleary Thx for answer. I'll try to explain my point: I need to set delay between moving cards, but when I try to use something like `Thread.Sleep(delay)` my window stop drawing. So its  only way i found to solve my problem.

Comment: @Altav1sta: I would recommend using WPF animations if you need to delay UI updates.

Comment: @StephenCleary Thx. I'll try to learn how can i use WPF animation here. But if it will be necessary to rewrite most part of code I have to abandon the idea to set delay between moving cards at all